# When updating a class instance variable is it better to update within a function or return the values and update at function call?

Tags: python, class, variables

I'm trying to understand which way is better to update the value. Within the function or the return?

```py
class MyClass:
  value = 123
newInstance = MyClass()
def UpdateValue():
  newInstance.value = 999
UpdateValue()
```

Or is this way better?

```py
class MyClass:
  value = 123
newInstance = MyClass()
def UpdateValue():
  return 999
newInstance.value = UpdateValue()
```

Comment: There's no answer to this, it depends on the application design. But you should give proper names to the functions. The second `UpdateValue()` doesn't actually update anything. It should be named `ReturnValue()`

Comment: in first version better send it as argument `def UpdateValue(newInstance)`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to do. There isn't a right answer per se...

I think it's best not to hardcode a return value into a function like this since there isn't actually much logic that you are doing in the function, so I think this is a clearer way of doing it:

```
class MyClass:
  value = 123
  
newInstance = MyClass()
newInstance.value = 999
```